# dump pg db from bash script .pgpass ignored

Tags: bash, centos7, postgresql

I'm trying to dump a postgreSQL database using our old method but I'm having some problems.

The old method simply trust all connections in localhost (in the pg_hba.conf) but the new one is set to `md5` for everyone.

This is the old script we use to dump the database

```
su postgres -c "pg_dump -U $DBUSER $DBNAME -Fc > /tmp/dbbackup.dump"
mv /tmp/dbbackup.dump /var/www/vhosts/$SITE/httpdocs/backup/
```

and is complaining about the password, so I create the `.pgpass` in `/root/` and then `chmod 0600` tried the command and it doesn't work, still complaining about the password, so I change owner and group to `postgres` but same error.

Where is the error? How can I backup my DB?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> su postgres -c "pg_dump . . .
>
> . . . and is complaining about the password, so I create the .pgpass in /root/

Remember what this usage of the **su** command does.

1. Change the execution contest to the named account.
2. Execute the given command.

You're asking the system to run the pg_dump command *as* the **postgres** account.

As such, the .pgpass file needs to be in the home directory of the **postgres** account, *not* that of the **root** account.

Comment: i was wandering about it, but I wasn't sure. So I need to create a postgres account? in Centos 7 if you install postgres via `yum` you don't have a home folder for the postgres user.

Comment: @Sebastiano: You're telling "su" that you want the pg_dump command run under the postgres account so I assumed you had one (which you should; never run your DBMS under the root account).  Bear in mind that the home directory for that postgres account may not be where you think it should: /var/lib/pgsql seems conventional these days.

Comment: Postgres run under a different account that is not even postgres, though I still have the postgres user in the DB, in Centos 7 yes I have `/var/lib/pgsql/<pg version>` so I need to move the `.pgpass` inside that folder?

Comment: @Sebastiano: "Postgres run under a different account that is not even postgres".  - OK, so whichever account you run the postgres [processes] under, the .pgpass file must appear in the home directory for /that/ account *and* you need to tell "su" to run the pg_dump command using /that/ account.